# Hadoop : set a variable like hashSet only once so that it can be utilized multiple times in each map task

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, configure

Hi I have a HashSet which needs to be utilized in each and every map task in hadoop. I dont want to initialize it multiple times. I heard that it is possible by setting the variable in configure function. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you haven't really understand the execution strategy of Hadoop.

If you are in distributed mode, you cannot share a collection (HashSet) throughout multiple map tasks. That is because Tasks are executed in their own JVM and it is not deterministic, even not with jvm reuse that your collection will still be there after the jvm has been resetted.

What you can do is you can setup a `HashSet` for each task at the beginning of the computation.

Therefore you can override the `setup(Context ctx)` method. This will be called before the map-method is called.

However you need enough ram to store the `HashSet` in each task.

If you don't have this capacity, you should take a distributed cache solution into account, but this will have overhead because each query must be serialized and deserialized. And it is not guranteed that the data is locally available, so this may take a lot longer than a collection within the task.

Answer (score 1):

Map tasks run on multiple nodes and each node has multiple JVMs in which the map tasks execute. So, as-is it's not possible to share a HashSet across map tasks. There are a couple of ways to alleviate the problem mentioned in the OP

1. Use [task jvm reuse](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html#Task+JVM+Reuse).
2. Use a [distributed cache solution](http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions).

Comment: Thanks Praveen for the quick turnaround. So, atleast is it possible to Initialize HashMap for each and every map task and utilise it for every record that this map task processes?

Comment: With the old MR API [configure](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConfigurable.html#configure(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf)) and with the new MR API [setup](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html#setup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context)) methods can be used to do the mapper initialization in which hashmap or anything can be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the HaseSet as static it will be initialized once per task 
If you need to to share it between tasks you need something shares such as distributed cache mentioned by Praveen

Answer (score 0):

The question is what you want to save? If it is time to initialize the set - then I would suggest using static variable which will be initialized if null and never cleaned. As a result each task, which happens to reuse the same JVM will use it. 
If the data is relatively small - you can serialize it as a string and path via configuration. 
If the data is big - you can use distributed cache to deliver data to each node, and then read it once per VM.